# Type 'Dictionary<T>' has no call signature. TypeScript, ngRx

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

i am trying to prepare a credit card application using ngRx. i have set up my actions, reducers and effects, but at the end of my reducer i encounter the above error, when i am trying to access a credit card id. The error is that the entities does not have a call back.

```
    export const getCurrentCreditCard = createSelector(
    getCreditCardFeatureState,
    getCurrentCreditCardId,
    state => state.entities(state.selectedCreditCardId)
    );
```

The code is a bit much...please here is a link to the git repo.
https://github.com/ProgrammeMitch/credit_card_store_ngrx
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with ngrx, but the error seems to indicate that `state.entities` is not a method, but rather a `Dictionary`.

I think maybe you simply need to use square brackets:

```
state => state.entities[state.selectedCreditCardId]
```